# Visio 2003/2010 Page List to Excel

Tags: excel, visio

is there a way to obtain and export multiple page names in a Visio Sheet? I do not want to export the objects in the page, just want to obtain a list of pages.

Example:
File Accounting_Layout.vsd, contains the following pages: Input, Output, Reports and
Unused.

How can i obtain this list and export to Excel?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built-in feature that would accomplish what you want, however if you are comfortable with VBA macros, then the following code will do what you need

```
Sub Demo()
    Set Excel = CreateObject("excel.application")
    Excel.Visible = True

    Set Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add
    Set Sheet = Workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    Let numpages = ActiveDocument.Pages.Count
    For i = 1 To numpages
        Set CurPage = ActiveDocument.Pages(i)
        Sheet.Cells(i, 1) = CurPage.Name
    Next i
End Sub
```